# database in Class controller in .net core 2.1

Tags: c#, controller, .net-core

I'm following a udemy course, about .net core 2.1 web development, I'm new to this, and most of it I understand although it all seems a bit strange as well. One of the strange parts I did not fully understand is in the code below. (despite that I used it everywhere). Although I do understand a Database is needed, I don't really get the idea about _db and db in below code. (i'm not a native English person) so the explanation escaped me. Could someone explain please what happens in the code below with _db and db ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GraniteHouse.Data;
using GraniteHouse.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace GraniteHouse.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
[Area("Admin")]
public class ProductTypesController : Controller
{

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public ProductTypesController(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;  //some kind of self refrence but why ???
    }
```

Comment: This is dependency injection. Basically the IoC container is injecting in an instance of `ApplicationDbContext`. Then it is assigned to a read-only field which is usable from your other methods in the class (this is needed since `db` is not usable outside of the method it is in, but `_db` is accessible **throughout the class**). https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/177649/what-is-constructor-injection

Comment: Is there something specific you're not understanding about it?  All this is doing is setting a private variable to the value that was passed in to the constructor.  Are you asking what a constructor is?  What assigning to a variable does?  Something else?